# Rails 5 Display values in Wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

Currently I'm trying to display a PDF for each wine in my Reservations View.

The problem I'm facing is that it only displays the PDF when I use the code below and shows me all reservations for each wine. I just want to display the specific reservation for each wine. I tried `@wines.reservations.start_date.strftime('%v')` for example but I get an undefined method error.

What would be the right way to display the specifics for each wine ?

```
    <div class="panel-body">
      <% @wines.each do |wine| %>
        <% wine.reservations.each do |reservation| %>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3" style="float:left">
              Bestellt am<br/>
              <%= reservation.start_date.strftime('%v') %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="float:left">
              <%= reservation.bottle %>x
              <%= link_to reservation.wine.wine_name, wine_path(reservation.wine) %><br/>
              Gesamt: <%= reservation.total %>€
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                <%= link_to user_path(reservation.user) do %>
                  <%= reservation.user.fullname %><br/>
                <% end %>
                <%= reservation.user.location %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr/>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation, not French, when writing in English.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= reservation.start_date %>
```

If you don't use the strftime(), does the start_date display? My hunch is the method is being called on string, when is can only be called on a date. Check your schema.rb file for the type of field start_date belongs to.

Or am I not understanding the question correctly?